# get_post_meta does not work in a WP_Query loop (returns empty array)

Tags: php, wordpress

This issue has had me stumped today. This code pretty much worked before today, albeit as top-level code in `functions.php` rather than as an admin page.

What this code does:

- Create an admin page. `dothing()` is the function that renders it.
- If you have a specific username, then start looping through the posts and printing out their metadata.

**Oddity:** Before any of the wp query stuff, if you try to print_r the get_post_meta of one of your posts (copy and paste the ID as an integer value manually), it will fetch the post meta for that one particular post.

Inside of the loop, what `get_post_meta` returns is an empty array.

```php
function dothing(){
    $username = wp_get_current_user()->user_login;

    if ( $username == 'foobar' )
    {
        echo '<div style="color: blue;max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">';

        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            $my_query->the_post();
            $myid = get_the_ID();
            echo 'the ID ' . $myid . ' has the meta fields: ';
            print_r( get_post_meta($myid) );
            echo '<br><br>';
        }

        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo '</div>';
    }
}

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'DoTHING', 'Dothing', 'manage_options', 'dothing', 'dothing', 'dashicons-tickets', 6  );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`get_post_custom()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_custom/) instead of [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). `get_post_meta()` is *designed* around fetching an individual key=>value pair, but defaults to an empty string which *should* return all fields (though I've found it to be inconsistent). I've found `get_post_custom()` to be more reliable when I need to sift through all of the meta fields.